# Get only some fields from array in Laravel requests

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, request

In input I have such an array:

```
array:1 [
  "prizes" => array:1 [
    1 => array:2 [
      "prize_id" => "1"
      "priority" => "1"
      "some_fields" => "some_value"
    ]
  ]
]
```

In controller, I try to get only two fields:

```
$request->only([
   'prizes.*.priority',
   'prizes.*.prize_id'
]);
```

but i should get this:

```
array:1 [
  "prizes" => array:1 [
    "*" => array:2 [
      "priority" => array:1 [
        0 => "1"
      ]
      "prize_id" => array:1 [
        0 => "1"
      ]
    ]
  ]
]
```

How to get array with needed fields?

Comment: You are only getting the needed fields right? it's returning a priority of 1 and a prize id of 1, just like your original array, and it isn't returning 'some_fields'?

Comment: @user10341554, I want to get such array as I received, but without "some_fields" => "some_value" - only fields that i need.

Comment: try `*.prizes.priority`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting an array as the result because you are using `.*.` which is  saying get ALL priorities for the prizes, which is why it is returning an array instead.

If you use the dot notation, you will access the only priority for the prize.

Like so:

`prizes.priority`

If you would like to validate for EVERY prize that you get coming in, you will use `*.` before  hand to access each array, like so:

`*.prizes.priority`

Edit: bit more information here https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#validating-arrays

Comment: When I use ```*.prizes.priority`` - I get this: ```array:1 [
  "*" => array:1 [
    "prizes" => array:2 [
      "priority" => array:7 [
        0 => null
        1 => null
        2 => null
        3 => null
        4 => null
        5 => null
        6 => null
      ]
      "prize_id" => array:7 [
        0 => null
        1 => null
        2 => null
        3 => null
        4 => null
        5 => null
        6 => null
      ]
    ]
  ]
]```

Comment: And when this ```prizes.priority``` - ```prizes.priority```